# Breadcrumbs Alignment

Tags: layout, breadcrumbs

Since aligning the breadcrumbs (it's actually a trace) to the left, our layout is more clean separating header (logo, login panel, navigation, breadcrumbs) from its content area (content title, toolbar, content itself).

Does any rule exist why breadcrumbs shouldn't be on the left side? What is commonly used and why?

Comment: Hi Zubi, could you add a screenshot? It's quite hard right now to understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Breadcrumb is usually aligned to left because it grants more readability. Cause we read from left to right, and the sequence of the pages linked has the same flow direction.

If you need more informations I suggest this article, it's really intresting.

[Breadcrumbs In Web Design: Examples And Best Practices](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/03/17/breadcrumbs-in-web-design-examples-and-best-practices-2/)